# How to redirect users to custom web page after sign in from okta sign in widget?

Tags: okta, okta-api

I’m building a React web app.
I used **OktaSignIn** widget code for setting up sign in page.
Once user provides the credentials and click on Sign in button its re-directing to Okta userHome page,
but i need to re-direct it to **custom web page**, instead of Okta userHome page.
Can someone help me with this.
Here is the image of sign in widget:
[image: Okta signin widget embedded in my React app]
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You have a couple of options:

- Update widget code to redirect to application after login. You can find more details here:

https://developer.okta.com/code/javascript/okta_sign-in_widget/#sign-in-to-okta-and-sso-directly-to-an-app

- Use 'Default App for Sign-In Widget' feature in Okta. You can find more details here:

https://help.okta.com/en/prod/Content/Topics/Settings/sign-in-widget-redirect.htm